# Find if $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{3}{n^2+3n}$ converges or not. If converges, find its sum.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find if $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2} \dfrac{3}{n^2+3n}$$

converges or not. If converges, find the sum.

I used the **integral** test to determine whether the series is convergent or not.

I found $$3\int^{\infty}_{2} \dfrac{1}{x^2+3x}\text{ dx} = \ln(5) - \ln(2)$$

and thus I can conclude that the series **converges.** But my question asks if it converges, find the sum. How? I evaluated the series at some points, and here is what I get:

$$\dfrac{3}{10} + \dfrac{3}{18} + \dfrac{3}{28}+\dfrac{3}{40} \dots$$
I don't see a pattern or anything, so how can I find the sum?

Comment: No pattern at all? The denominators seem to be increasing by $2$ more each time...

Comment: Can you separate the fraction and telescope ;)

Comment: HINT!!!(you can)  3/(x^3+3x) = 1/x - 1/(x+3)

Comment: For convergence simply say $n^2+3n>n^2$ thus $|a_n|<\frac{3}{n^2}$ which converges. The integral test is not necessary when it is possible to roughly upper bound.

Comment: I haven't learned that convergence test yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{n(n+3)} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right) =&\  \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{8}\right)+\ldots\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: But then wouldn't that go on forever?

Comment: Observe $-\frac{1}{5}$ cancels out with $\frac{1}{5}$ and $-\frac{1}{6}$ will cancel out $\frac{1}{6}$, etc.

Comment: If you prefer you have $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+3} = \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3} \right), $$ so your series is actually the sum of three telescopic series.

Comment: Or you could just re-index the sum. $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac 1n - \sum\limits_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac 1n=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{4}\frac 1n$.

Comment: @zwim, on the left you have two divergent series, so this is strongly unformal. Use partial sums rather.

Comment: @JackyChong I agree that it cancels out, but how would I simplify the $$\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} \dots$$

Comment: @KSplitX If the terms cancel out and you only have three terms left then just add it up.

Comment: @szw1710 The original serie converges absolutely, we are allowed to do any manipulating we want, but I agree partial sums would be better. Note that the telescoping presentation suffer the same symptom if we want to be scrupulous.